# teamcity CI fastlane increment build number

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, fastlane, incremental-build

does anybody know and actually figured out how to setup both FASTLANE and TEAMCITY CI server with automatic build incrementing? There seem to be no clear guide on how to do it anywhere.

Thank you.

Comment: is this helpful? https://medium.com/xcblog/ios-continuous-deployment-with-fastlane-and-ansible-part-1-bc3e50fcc058